# Get modal answer Discord.js V14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Hello I have a problem that i cant solve. I am developing a bot using discord.js v14. So, I'm making a modal and i try to get modal answer. In the documentation, it says that i need to do interaction.fields.getTextInputValue("ModalInput") But it show me an error.

Here, the error:

```
TypeError: modal.getTextInputValue is not a function
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\rorol\Desktop\Dev\Bot Avocat Stalya\events\CreateTicket.js:64:28)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

And here, you have CreateTicket.js:

```
const { InteractionType, ActionRowBuilder, Events, ModalBuilder, TextInputBuilder, TextInputStyle, ChannelType, PermissionsBitField } = require("discord.js");
const interactionCreate = require("./interactionCreate");


const chalk = require("chalk")

 module.exports = {
    name: Events.InteractionCreate,
    execute: async(interaction, modal) => {
        
        if(!interaction.isButton()) return;
        
        if(!interaction.customId !== "candidature" ) {

            
            
            const modal = new ModalBuilder()
            .setCustomId('candidaturemodal')
            .setTitle('Candidature')

            const PrenomInput = new TextInputBuilder()
                .setCustomId('PresentationInput')
                .setLabel('Présente toi IRL :')
                .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Paragraph);
            
            const CandidatureInput = new TextInputBuilder()
                .setCustomId('NomPrenomInput')
                .setLabel('Nom Prénom RP :')
                .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short);

            const AgeInput = new TextInputBuilder()
                .setCustomId('AgeInput')
                .setLabel('Âge de ton personnage :')
                .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short);

            const DiplomeInput = new TextInputBuilder()
                .setCustomId('DiplomeInput')
                .setLabel('Diplômes: ')
                .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short);

            const MotivationInput = new TextInputBuilder()
                .setCustomId('MotivationsInput')
                .setLabel('Motivations :')
                .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Paragraph);


            
            const ActionRow1 = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(PrenomInput);
            const ActionRow2 = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(CandidatureInput);
            const ActionRow3 = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(AgeInput);
            const ActionRow4 = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(MotivationInput);
            const ActionRow5 = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(DiplomeInput);


            modal.addComponents(ActionRow1, ActionRow2, ActionRow3,ActionRow5, ActionRow4)
            
            await interaction.showModal(modal);


            if (interaction.customId === 'candidaturemodal') {
            await interaction.reply({ content: 'Your submission was received successfully!' });
            }

            const Prenomirl = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('PrenomInput')
            const NomPrenom = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('CandidatureInput')
            const Age = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('AgeInput')
            const Motivation = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('MotivationInput')
            const Diplomes = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('DiplomeInput')

            guild.channels.create({
                
                name: `Candidature-${user.interaction.tag}`, 
                type: ChannelType.GuildText,
                permissionOverwrites: [
                    
                    {
                        id: interaction.guild.id,
                        deny: [PermissionsBitField.Flags.ViewChannel],
                    },
                    {
                        id: interaction.user.id,
                        allow: [PermissionsBitField.Flags.ViewChannel],
                    },
                ],
            });
        };

    }
}
```

If someone can help me it will help me a lot, thanks you

Answer (score 0):

You receieve [ModalSubmitFields](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/ModalSubmitFields) only through [ModalSubmitInteraction#fields](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/ModalSubmitInteraction?scrollTo=fields).

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', (interaction) => {
    if (interaction.isModalSubmit()) {
        const value = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('customId');
    }
})
```

The above method will work only when a modal is submitted.

Alternatively, you can use an [InteractionCollector](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/InteractionCollector) to collect modal responses.

```js
const { InteractionCollector, ComponentType } = require('discord.js');

const collector = new InteractionCollector(client, {
    componentType: ComponentType.TextInput,
    // configure your options
});

collector.on('collect', async (i) => {
    // handle the same way as 'interactionCreate' with 'i'
});
```